# Можно ли использовать bootstrap в перемешку с обычной адаптивной вёрсткой

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

У меня есть проект, где я хочу использовать и `bootstrap`, и обычную адаптивную вёрстку от руки, так скажем

Будет ли верно с точки зрения стандартов\правильности разметки использовать и то, и то?

Или я вынужден использовать исключительно `bootstrap` во всей вёрстке

Comment: о каких стандартах идет речь?

Comment: @Grundy в целом мне это кажется каким-то неправильным мероприятием, почему - не знаю, вот и решил уточнить.

Comment: почему тебе кажется это неправильным?

Comment: Это же твой проект. Ты волен его делать как тебе удобнее. Если, конечно, тебе заказчик не определил некие ограничения при постановке задачи на разработку...

Comment: Спасибо, всё понятно теперь)

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn правильнее будет спрашивать не о стандартах, а о "best practice". Тогда возможно ответы будут другие.